# Health Startup illustration

Tags: website-design, illustration

[image: Zocdoc Doctor Illustration]

I am working on a health startup and was thinking of building some character unique to my startup as zocdoc does to explain itself.
Will a sketch doctor seem derivative? 
PS: My site would be frequented by mid to old aged users.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately brainstorming and idea gathering is not really on topic here. If you can rephrase your question so that *specific*, creditable, answers are possible, it may be more on-topic. However, as it stands this question may be put on hold.

Comment: I'd lean towards cliche more than derivative, but sometimes cliche's work. They are cliche for a reason, after all.